# Filter content by own content or admin

Tags: views, entities

So I have an entity reference field on a node, the widget is a select-box.

I want so that an user can choose one of their own authored nodes as a reference OR if an admin is logged in, they can choose any content. So admins should be able to bypass this restriction (with a permission, role or something).

I tried building a view based on this, but the contextual filter seems to be the problem. I can't really do any either/or kind of thing with contextual filter.

Comment: There is OR in views filters available, right? Have you tried it? What's your problem with it?

Comment: @Mołot I can't filter by current user's content in views filters. Contextual filter works, but there's no way to call that in views filters.

Comment: Why can't you? I do it on http://molot.pl to allow people to only reference their gifts on their gift lists, and it works, no sweat. And no need for contextual, just filters.

Comment: I added a filter "Content: Author uid". I can't give it current user's uid, it just wants a list of uids.

Comment: Have you related your view to users? Relationships are on top right...

Comment: Yes I have added "Content: Author" relationship, but that doesn't give anymore choices in the dialog.

Comment: I have `(author) User: Current (Yes)` set up in filters and it's simply there, working.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I see what you mean now! That seems to work as expected. But now I can't do that OR action since I can't get current user's info in Filter... But that's another problem. Thanks!

Comment: @molot - you going to make this an answer?

Comment: @autopoietic yes, I did, but I don't have time to wrote it properly and with screenshots now, so if you can write a good quality answer with that info, don't hesitate.

Comment: @molot will do, didn't want to step on your toes

Comment: @autopoietic thanks for asking. If I was in the process of writing my own answer, I'd ask you to wait. But I'm not. Not enough time. So go on and write it if you have time to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Background

> So I have an entity reference field on a node, the widget is a
> select-box.

You (Risse) have already done this, but to make this clear for other users, this involves adding an entity reference field to a content type and in the field settings changing from the default 'Simple..' to 'Views..':

[image]

Now the select list used to choose a referenced entity (in this case a node), will use views to create the select list, allowing us to customise the nodes listed. In the example above I have created a view (and added an 'Entity Reference' display) and called it entity_reference_select.

> I want so that an user can choose one of their own authored nodes as a
> reference OR if an admin is logged in, they can choose any content. So
> admins should be able to bypass this restriction (with a permission,
> role or something).

It is easy enough to list only nodes by the current author using the filter "Content: Author uid" in the view (as per @molot above). Unfortunately this does allow us to differentiate the results for admin users.

An appropriate response might initially seen to involve an OR statement in the views filters to allow admin user to see all nodes in the select list, and other users to only see their own nodes. Unfortunately there are two issues with this:

- There is no way to create a views **Relationship** to the current user in order to evaluate the current user's roles in the filters section
- An OR conditional in the filters will **remove** options, not add them, so would  remove non authored nodes from an admin role user anyway

### Solution

Provide a default value for a contextual filter which is defined by PHP. This means we can specify which user(author) we are going to filter the results by, which would be the current user (fetched from the global $user object) unless the current user has the 'administrator' role, in which case we list nodes authored by **all** users.

[image]